# Cron job not working on URL

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, cron

I'm using WordPress and want to delete unattached media. I have created the script but want to run through Cron job. I have created a page and call the template in page everything is working fine. But when I'm trying the URL in Cron job it is not working.

```
*/5 * * * * wget -O - http://www.example.com/delete-trashed-products >/dev/null 2>&1

*/5 * * * * wget (same link)

*/5 * * * * curl (same link)

*/5 * * * * GET (same link)
```

I'm unable to add all URLs. I have run these scripts after 5 minutes interval but nothing worked.

Can anybody please help me to figure out the problem?

Comment: use full path of `wget`. eg: `*/5 * * * *  /usr/bin/wget -O - http://www.example.com/delete-trashed-products >/dev/null 2>&1` note: you are redirecting the output and error to `null`

Comment: You may want to consider using `wp_schedule_event` (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event). It's a way to run a hook at a scheduled time and would be cleaner overall. I know it's doesn't answer your question directly but may help.

Comment: Thanks @MillerMedia i have also tried but the script makes your site slow down so i just use only server cron job. But now my server support team is working on the issue it is only the siteground server issue. Thanks all for your help and support. :)